# Integrate 3rd party input props to Material UI's TextField

Tags: reactjs, input, material-ui, textfield, credit-card

I'm using a library called [react-payment-inputs](https://github.com/medipass/react-payment-inputs) to accept credit card numbers.
The library provides input getter props that can be used to handle credit card input.

I'm able to use the getter prop methods with a simple input like this: `<input {...getCardNumberProps()} />`.

However, when doing the same with `TextField` I get an error from within the library:
`Error: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined` at `Object.formatCardNumber`

Here's the code showing the issue.

```
import React from "react";
import { Grid, TextField } from "@material-ui/core";
import { usePaymentInputs } from "react-payment-inputs";

export default () => {
  const { getCardNumberProps } = usePaymentInputs();

  return (
    <Grid item xs={12}>
      {/* App blows up, see sandbox for demo */}
      <TextField {...getCardNumberProps()} />

      {/* If you uncomment then it shows 2 input boxes but the app doesnt blow up  */}
      {/* <input {...getCardNumberProps()} /> */}

      {/* If you uncomment this, then there is only 1 input box
      but the styling from the library (space after every 4 digits)
      is lost */}
      {/* <input {...getCardNumberProps()} type="hidden" /> */}
    </Grid>
  );
};
```

Here is a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/winter-hooks-k6h6w?file=/src/CreditCardProperty.js) link showing the issue.

The library does have [documentation](https://github.com/medipass/react-payment-inputs#using-a-third-party-ui-library) on how to integrate with any 3rd party UI library. However, it doesn't provide a Material UI example.
How can I forward these external props from `TextField` to the inner input correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed it by using the inputProps property of TextField like this:

```
<TextField inputProps={getCardNumberProps({}) />
```

This works because it sends the getter methods to the `input` wrapped inside the `TextField` material element.